# Setting roles through rolify in FactoryBot definition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise, factory-bot

I am using devise, rolify and cancan. I'm also using RSpec with FactoryBot for testing. Right now I'm working on some tests and I want to define users with different roles for those tests. Here is my current guess for how to do that using FactoryBot:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :user do
    name 'Test User'
    email 'example@example.com'
    password 'please'
    password_confirmation 'please'
    # required if the Devise Confirmable module is used
    confirmed_at Time.now

    factory :admin do
        self.has_role :admin
    end

    factory :curator do
        self.has_role :curator
    end

    factory :super_admin do
        self.has_role :super_admin
    end
  end
end
```

Here are some of my tests which don't seem to be written correctly:
require 'spec_helper'

```
describe "Pages" do
    subject { page }

    before do
        @newpage = FactoryBot.create(:page)
        @newpage.save
    end

    context 'not logged in' do
        it_behaves_like 'not admin'
    end

    context 'logged in' do

        context 'as user' do
            before do
                @user = FactoryBot.create(:user)
                sign_in @user
            end

            it_behaves_like 'not admin'
        end

        context 'as curator' do
            before do
                @curator = FactoryBot.create(:curator)
                sign_in @curator
            end

            it_behaves_like 'not admin'
        end

        context 'as admin' do
            before do
                @admin = FactoryBot.create(:admin)
                sign_in @admin
            end

            it_behaves_like 'admin'
        end

        context 'as super admin' do
            before do
                @super_admin = FactoryBot.create(:super_admin)
                sign_in @super_admin
            end

            it_behaves_like 'admin'
        end
    end
end
```

When I run the specs I these are my errors:

```
1) Pages logged in as admin behaves like admin can show page 
 Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `has_role=' for #<User:0x007f883384d178>
 Shared Example Group: "admin" called from ./spec/requests/pages_spec.rb:41
 # ./spec/requests/pages_spec.rb:37:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

2) Pages logged in as curator behaves like not admin can show page 
 Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
 ArgumentError:
   Factory not registered: curator
 Shared Example Group: "not admin" called from ./spec/requests/pages_spec.rb:32
 # ./spec/requests/pages_spec.rb:28:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

3) Pages logged in as super admin behaves like admin can show page 
 Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
 ArgumentError:
   Factory not registered: super_admin
 Shared Example Group: "admin" called from ./spec/requests/pages_spec.rb:50
 # ./spec/requests/pages_spec.rb:46:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Note: FactoryBot was previously called FactoryGirl

Answer (score 64, accepted):

I would rather use FactoryBot's `after(:create)` [callback](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md) to create roles (also see [this](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify/issues/99) issue for Rolify).

Furthermore the method `has_role?` is used to **check** if a user has a specific role, to **set** a specific role you should use the `add_role` method.

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :user do
    name 'Test User'
    email 'example@example.com'
    password 'please'
    password_confirmation 'please'
    # required if the Devise Confirmable module is used
    confirmed_at Time.now

    factory :admin do
        after(:create) {|user| user.add_role(:admin)}
    end

    factory :curator do
        after(:create) {|user| user.add_role(:curator)}
    end

    factory :super_admin do
        after(:create) {|user| user.add_role(:super_admin)}
    end
  end
end
```

Note: FactoryBot was previously called FactoryGirl

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this the next time. I have since moved on to another method for handling user roles.

Comment: Also look into `before(:create)`, works as well but different callback.