# NoMethodError: undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass (Rspec/factory girl/cancan/devise)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise, factory-bot, cancan

I am following Hartl's Rails tutorial but I used devise/cancan/rolify so some things are not the same.

On my users_pages_spec.rb test, I keep getting this error in spite of all I tried:

```
1) User pages index delete links as an admin user 
 Failure/Error: sign_in @superadmin
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass
 # ./spec/support/utilities.rb:14:in `sign_in'
 # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:91:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'

2) User pages index delete links as an admin user 
 Failure/Error: sign_in @superadmin
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass
 # ./spec/support/utilities.rb:14:in `sign_in'
 # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:91:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'

3) User pages index delete links as an admin user should be able to delete another user
 Failure/Error: sign_in @superadmin
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass
 # ./spec/support/utilities.rb:14:in `sign_in'
 # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:91:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'

4) User pages index delete links as an admin user 
 Failure/Error: sign_in @superadmin
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass
 # ./spec/support/utilities.rb:14:in `sign_in'
 # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:91:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I don't understand why, does nil::nilClass mean factory girl actually does not manage to create this superadmin user?

Here is the sample of my user_pages_spec.rb  file:

```
require 'spec_helper'
require 'cancan/matchers'

# Test if targeted words appears in displayed content

describe "User pages" do

subject { page }
let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
let(:wrong_user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user, email: "wrong@example.com") }
let(:non_admin) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
let(:submit) { "Sign in" }

describe "index" do
  describe "delete links" do

  it { should_not have_link('delete') }

  describe "as an admin user" do
    let(:superadmin) { FactoryGirl.create(:superadmin) }
    before do
      sign_in @superadmin
      visit users_path
    end
    it { should have_title('List of users') }

    it { should have_link('delete', href: user_path(User.first)) }
    it "should be able to delete another user" do
      expect { click_link('delete') }.to change(User, :count).by(-1)
    end
    it { should_not have_link('delete', href: user_path(superadmin)) }
  end
end
end
end
```

my spec/utilities.rb defining sign_in method

```
include ApplicationHelper

def sign_in(user)
visit new_user_session_path
fill_in "Email",        with: user.email
fill_in "Password", with: user.password
click_button "Login"
#populate cookie when not using capybara
cookies[:authentication_token] = user.authentication_token
end
```

and my spec/factories/user.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
factory :user do
sequence(:name)  { |n| "Person #{n}" }
sequence(:email) { |n| "person_#{n}@example.com"}   
password "beta"
password_confirmation "beta"
# required if the Devise Confirmable module is used
confirmed_at Time.now
confirmation_token nil

factory :superadmin do
  after(:create) {|user| user.add_role(:superadmin)}
end
end

end
```

I do have in cancan/rolify a superadmin role defined.

If anybody has a clue, I'd take it! i can update the question with additional file needed if not already here.

Comment: try to fill data in email attribute

Comment: @MostafaHussein but i thought that by setting in factories a :superadmin and then writing in user_page_spec.rb     let(:superadmin) { FactoryGirl.create(:superadmin) }, i was providing email and password to this "dummy" admin user. i don't know how to "fill data in email attribute".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `let` call is setting `superadmin`, but you're referencing `@superadmin`, which is going to be `nil`, since it hasn't been set. BTW, this is a good reason to generally avoid using instance variables in your tests, as they silently default to `nil` when referenced if uninitialized.

Comment: actually i don't think it's the root of the problem because just before posting the question i was actually doing without the @ ! :) but i was gettign the error has_role not defined. then i saw this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12380989/setting-roles-through-rolify-in-factorygirl-definition and the guy was using @, so i did too to try and at least it seems it understands now has_role. But now it's the email that is a problem:) I'm lost...

Comment: I didn't mean to imply that if you fixed the problem I identified that there wouldn't be others. Also, in the question you cited, the user used the `@` in both the assignment and the reference, which you can too. You just can't assign to one variable and reference another.  If you post the error you get after correcting the problem of referencing an unassigned variable and show the related code, we can help you further. As is, you don't show where "has_role" is referenced.

Comment: thanks i removed the @ and it worked, by miracle maybe server restart) i don't even get the add_role pb any more. Thanks!