# Factory will create one object with a role, but not two

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot, rolify

I am using rolify with a User model and a Task model (Rails 4). One of the roles a user can have is "owner." I want to use Factory Girl to create a user object and assign it a role. Here is my factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :task do  
    owner "Steve"
    agency "an agency"
    facility "a facility"
    description "This task must absolutely be done"
    due_date "2013-12-22 03:57:37"
    completed_date "2013-12-22 03:57:37"

    factory :task_with_owner do
      ignore do
        user_id nil
      end

      after(:create) do |task, user_id|
        User.find(user_id).add_role :owner, task
      end
    end 
  end
end
```

This spec passes:

```
  it 'is capable of creating a valid object with owner' do
    @user = create(:user)
    task = create(:task_with_owner, user_id: @user.id)
    expect(@user.has_role? :owner, task).to be_true
  end
```

This spec fails:

```
  it 'is capable of creating two valid objects with an owner' do
    @user = create(:user, username: 'janeblow')
    task = create(:task_with_owner, user_id: @user.id)
    expect(@user.has_role? :owner, task).to be_true
    task = create(:task_with_owner, user_id: @user.id)
    expect(@user.has_role? :owner, task).to be_true
  end
```

The error is:

```
Failure/Error: task = create(:task_with_owner, user_id: @user.id)                                   
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound:                                                                       
  Couldn't find User with id=#<#<Class:0x000000050f5e10>:0x00000004c9ed08>                          
 # ./spec/factories/tasks.rb:19:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'                            
 # ./spec/models/role_spec.rb:15:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Why?

Comment: Why is your `:task_with_owner` factory nested within the `:task` factory?

Comment: I want `:task_with_owner` to inherit the attributes I set up for `:task`.

Comment: You should create a normal factory then, but set the parent to `task`. Eg: `factory :task_with_owner, parent: :task do ... end`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your after(:create) block looks a little wrong. Try changing it to the following:

```
after(:create) do |task, vars|
  User.find(vars.user_id).add_role :owner, task
end
```

Then re-run your failing spec.

Because you told the factory to ignore the `user_id` being passed in and to use `nil` instead, in your `after(:create)` block you have to access it from the passed in attributes (in the second block argument, vars in this case). You were almost there, but were passing the object factory_girl uses to hold the attributes rather than the attribute itself from within that object.

See the `Transient Attributes` section here for another example - https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md

Comment: It's not a simple association. Ultimately users will have a variety of roles with respect to tasks (they could be the owner, or just want to be CC:'d on updates, or just want the ability to view the task). So there's a join table in between (this is what rolify takes care of). I don't think it's a problem with the callback approach or nesting - see this answer to a related problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12380989/setting-roles-through-rolify-in-factorygirl-definition

Comment: Ah ok ... I'll modify my answer. Hang on

Comment: Well done sir. I've read that example of Transient Attributes a zillion times and could never figure out for sure what the heck was happening with the second argument to the `after` block. Now it is obvious - thanks.

Comment: You're very welcome. I should go get some sleep now :)

Comment: For what it's worth to future generations, now that I understand how that works I can just pass the `@user` object when I create the task in the spec and call `vars.user.add_role...` so I don't have to hit the database. Using `find` and the id was just a desperate flailing hack when I couldn't get passing the object itself to work at all.